# Wilcoxon test for independent groups, but with repeated measurements

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I need to compare the average amount of money earned by the control group versus the experimental group on a trial level. Each group has 25 subjects.
The variable doesn't have a normal distribution, and the people from each group are different, so they're *independent samples*, and I should do a Wilcoxon sum rank test/ Mann-Whitney.

**BUT:** each subject earned money 240 times, So I have *240 trials/observations coming from the same subject*. Meaning I have repeated measures on this level.

The following is what I currently have in R:

```
wilcox.test(df$Earnings ~ df$Group, 
            mu=0, 
            conf.int=T, 
            conf.level= 0.95, 
            paired= F,
            var.eq=F,
            exact = F,   
            correct= F)
```

Is there a way to account for the repeated measures of the trials when comparing two independent groups?

Comment: [Friedman's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) (like a nonparametric repeated measures ANOVA)?

Comment: Adding random intercepts (subject as a random effect) would probably work best here.  You can do that with the R `ordinal` package, and others.